# Return multiple count rows number in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two table   rating   and   rate_table

on rating  table I have

```
 ratingID,     ratingname,          userID.           
    1            RateA               admin      
    2            RateB               Admin 
    3            RateC               0001
```

On rate_table I have

```
ratingID     come                     userID 
1            xxxx                      0001
2            xxxxx                     0001 
2            xxxxx                     0001
3            xxxx                      0001
2            xxxxx                     0001
1            xxxxx                     0001
```

I'm  expecting  a result like this  but it seems.    not to work.

```
RateA    2 
RateB.   3
RateC    1
```

This is  what I have  tried:

```
<?php public function rating() {
 $this -> jpt_connect();
 $userID= $this ->users_info('userID');
 $rating_ar = array();
 $sql =mysql_query("SELECT
                      rt.ratingname,
                      COUNT(follows.userID) as id
                    FROM rating as rt
                    LEFT JOIN rate_table    as tr 
                    ON.  (tr.userID = '$userID')
                         AND (tr.ratingID = rt.ratingID )
                    WHERE rt.userID ='admin'
                       OR rt.userID='$userID' ")
or   die(mysql_error());
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$rating_ar[] =$row;
}
return $rating_ar;
}
$j = new jkp();
$array =$j -> rating();
?>
```

How can I count the rate row in join with the rating name
Please how can I access the var array ;
I will like send all the data   that is coming from      the db inside this array.
I tried  but nothing happen Thanks in advance

Comment: where is `rate_table.followerID` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Join ratings to rating objects and group by rating object:

```
select o.name, count(1) votes
from votes v
join objects o ON o.id = v.object_id
group by o.id;
```

As seen on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c1ebb/1

I've renamed the tables, because I didn't get yours:

```
OBJECTS ( id, name )
VOTES ( object_id )
```

(only the relevant columns)

**edit** Or maybe I didn't understand the problem at all. Follows? The users are relevant?